# Google Analytics Universal Cross Domain Tracking not working properly

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, universal

I have a website blog.arkency.com and a shop https://arkency.dpdcart.com/ . I use autolinker for tracking users between them. Here is how it is configured on blog.arkency.com :

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-35104719-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['dpdcart.com', 'rails-refactoring.com', 'bit.ly']);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

And on `arkency.dpdcart.com` :

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-35104719-1', 'auto', {
  'allowLinker': true
});


ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I performed a test going through a buying sequence:

- http://blog.arkency.com/2015/09/testing-race-conditions/
- https://arkency.dpdcart.com/
- paypal
- https://arkency.dpdcart.com/

And the landing page and source/medium display incorrectly in GA:

[image: landing page]

Because it is my own website and it should not be counted as referral.

[image: exclusion list]
[image: configuration]

I checked the HTTP requests to GA when I was doing my research and they looked like that:

```
Request URL:https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1&_v=j38&a=1255711451&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Farkency.dpdcart.com%2F%3F_ga%3D1.79491091.621357523.1441479797&dr=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.arkency.com%2F2015%2F09%2Ftesting-race-conditions%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Home%20%7C%20Arkency&sd=24-bit&sr=1600x900&vp=834x813&je=1&fl=18.0%20r0&_u=AgAAAEABI~&jid=1715718675&cid=621357523.1441479797&tid=UA-35104719-1&_r=1&z=1162483874

Request URL:https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j38&a=2097630504&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Farkency.dpdcart.com%2Fcart%2Fview%3Freferer%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Farkency.dpdcart.com%252F%26product_id%3D113689-react-js-by-example%26__dpd_cart%3De6f30ed5-9ca4-49b5-afa2-7a606ae95f91&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=View%20Cart%20%7C%20Arkency&sd=24-bit&sr=1600x900&vp=834x813&je=1&fl=18.0%20r0&_u=AACAAEABI~&jid=&cid=621357523.1441479797&tid=UA-35104719-1&z=1979770742

Request URL:https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j38&a=1952143645&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Farkency.dpdcart.com%2Fcart%2Fview%3F__dpd_cart%3De6f30ed5-9ca4-49b5-afa2-7a606ae95f91&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=View%20Cart%20%7C%20Arkency&sd=24-bit&sr=1600x900&vp=849x813&je=1&fl=18.0%20r0&_u=AACAAEABI~&jid=&cid=621357523.1441479797&tid=UA-35104719-1&z=1256192494

Request URL:https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j38&a=1347158491&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Farkency.dpdcart.com%2Fcart%2Fdeliver%3Fpurchase_id%3DXXXXXXXX%26salt%3DYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY&dr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com%2Fpl%2Fcgi-bin%2Fwebscr%3Fcmd%3D_flow%26SESSION%3DEf-eKJ5bQypdlCxkhwHSjyO0-D6VqMIpt_fx94q7eflrZyhE3SuxdlckyuC%26dispatch%3D50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198d1a93361f052308ac20c1249d8113f4c&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Your%20Purchase%20%7C%20Arkency&sd=24-bit&sr=1600x900&vp=1214x813&je=1&fl=18.0%20r0&_u=CCCAAEATI~&jid=&cid=621357523.1441479797&tid=UA-35104719-1&z=438758986

Request URL:https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j38&a=1347158491&t=transaction&cu=USD&_s=2&dl=https%3A%2F%2Farkency.dpdcart.com%2Fcart%2Fdeliver%3Fpurchase_id%3DXXXXXXXX%26salt%3DYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY&dr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com%2Fpl%2Fcgi-bin%2Fwebscr%3Fcmd%3D_flow%26SESSION%3DEf-eKJ5bQypdlCxkhwHSjyO0-D6VqMIpt_fx94q7eflrZyhE3SuxdlckyuC%26dispatch%3D50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198d1a93361f052308ac20c1249d8113f4c&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Your%20Purchase%20%7C%20Arkency&sd=24-bit&sr=1600x900&vp=1214x813&je=1&fl=18.0%20r0&_u=CCCAAEATI~&jid=&cid=621357523.1441479797&tid=UA-35104719-1&ti=XXXXXXXX&ta=Arkency&tr=1.00&ts=0.00&tt=0.00&z=1172984422

Request URL:https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j38&a=1347158491&t=item&cu=USD&_s=3&dl=https%3A%2F%2Farkency.dpdcart.com%2Fcart%2Fdeliver%3Fpurchase_id%3DXXXXXXXX%26salt%3DYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY&dr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com%2Fpl%2Fcgi-bin%2Fwebscr%3Fcmd%3D_flow%26SESSION%3DEf-eKJ5bQypdlCxkhwHSjyO0-D6VqMIpt_fx94q7eflrZyhE3SuxdlckyuC%26dispatch%3D50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198d1a93361f052308ac20c1249d8113f4c&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Your%20Purchase%20%7C%20Arkency&sd=24-bit&sr=1600x900&vp=1214x813&je=1&fl=18.0%20r0&_u=CCCAAEATI~&jid=&cid=621357523.1441479797&tid=UA-35104719-1&ti=XXXXXXXX&in=React.js%20by%20example&ic=113689&ip=49.00&iq=1&z=1870355733
```

As you can see the `cid` parameter on first domain and on the other domain was identical so the autoLinker seems to be working. **But it still seems to be starting a new session with new source/medium/landing page** and the ecommerce results are attached to that session.

I would be very glad for any help regarding what should be changed, fixed to have it working.